# react native fullwidth background image 'Android'

Tags: android, react-native, background-image

I used image as container to have a fullwidth background. It runs correctly in emulator, but when I open application on the device, background is white.
Thank you for attantion

```
<Container>
    <Content>
      <Image 
        style={styles.bgImage}
        source={require('../../../images/login_bg.png')}>
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../../../images/logo.png')} />
          <Button
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {this.logIn(username, password)}}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <Text style={styles.version}>Version 4.0.0</Text>
          <Text style={styles.copyright}>&copy; All rights reserved. Araqich is registered trademark of Araqich LLC.</Text>
        </View>
      </Image>
    </Content>
  </Container>
```

Comment: Put `alignSelf: 'stretch'` as a style for the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an image was exported from psd not correctly )
It was giving blob error, which said that the image is overwritten

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `alignSelf: 'stretch'`
it will work

Comment: that doesn't work because in device image is not appearing

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable as below:

```
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

and in your style

```
add : "width : width" with your other attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is a good way to do. but i use my image as a container with flex: 1 , width: null, height: null
and it work for me on both platform in production. :

```
return(
<Image  source={require('/background_image.png')} style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: null }} >

[ ... your JSX ... ]

</Image>
);
```